# Import csv utf-8 database in intellij idae

Tags: database, intellij-idea, unicode, utf-8, intellij-14

I exported my oracle database datas into csv file(in intellij idae)...then I cleaned all databases and create theme again...when I imported that database it does not import in correct utf-8 format although I can see my datas in correct utf-8 in notepad
[image]

Comment: if you can add error log / picture of imported data (could help us to find the problem)

Comment: @Blag I added picture of imported data...I don't have any error